Finding maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$
I came across the question of finding maximal ideals in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$.
$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2) = \{ax+b : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
For any prime, $p$, $(x) \subset (x,p)$ and $(p) \subset (x,p)$. So, the principal ideals of the ring are not maximal.
I am guessing the maximal ideals are of the form $(x,p)$. Is it right, and if so how to prove it?
Thanks in advance.

A hint: quotienting by a maximal ideal must result in a field, so $x$ must be quotiented away, since it's a zero divisor. Do that first to obtain $\mathbb Z$, then take it from there.

Slightly different spin on the hint above: a maximal ideal of the ring is prime, and contains the element $x^2$... that helps you toward your conjecture.

You're right, but in determining that the principal ideals are not maximal, you should also consider ideals of the form $(ax + b)$. Note, for instance, that $(2x,2) \subset (x + 2)$.

Compare with this post.
